# how to connect oracle database by using iphone webserives

Tags: iphone, web-services

1.How to connect oracle database by using iphone webservices?

2.I was developed an app for iPhone that services are interact with phpmyadmin database.

3.But i want to how to interact with oracle database. please provide services. how to

developer code in server?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the web services provide by the your php developers team they develop the response in XML or JSON format which you access in your app by using NSXML parser or JSON parsing.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you want to create a web service for your application. You can use PHP for this purpose.
2. Then you can call that web service from your Objective-C code.

The below links will help.
 a. You can refer to [NSMutablerequest class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information on creating a web service request.
 
b. You can refer [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app) tutorial for creating a simple web service for an iOS application.